# php var subtract one every second

Tags: php, cron

I have a php var, which indicates how long it takes before the user can perform the next operation.
I want to display this, using js, However I dont want js to execute the substraction but PHP.
I considered using a cronjob, but that has a min-interval of 1 minute.
Is there any(simple) solution to this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time making sense of your post.  Are you designing a web page?  what do you need subtraction for?  do you have a framework set up?  can you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so that we can have some context?

Answer (score 3):

Why not store a timestamp in the DB of the next time the user can perform the next operation?  It can then be used to work out the difference between the current timestamp and the one in the DB and thus you have the seconds left until they can perform that action.